# Formula for returning random date within a range from a date in another column in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am mocking up data. I have an order date column and a promise date column. I have populated the promise date column and I would like to populate the order date column with random dates which are within a certain number of days before the corresponding promise date. What would be the formula which would allow me to do this.

Furthermore, if possible, I would like to create a conditional which specifies that range depending on another column, which is ship option (standard, two day shipping, etc.). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=RANDBETWEEN(BOTTOM_NUMBER,TOP_NUMBER)

This will give you an integer greater than or equal to the bottom integer and less than of equal to the top number.

Why is this useful to you?  The date in excel is actually the number of days since 1900/01/00.  A quick way to determine your upper and lower bounding numbers would be to enter the dates in a cell.  Then change the formatting of that cell to general.  Take the integer that is displayed and place it in the bottom or top number position in the formula above as required.

Be aware that this is a volatile function.  This means it will recalculate every time something on the worksheet changes.  If you want to lock your dates in after generating them, you could turn automatic calculation off, or you could copy the data and paste special and paste the values.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I got it. The formula goes like this:

=IF(C2="Basic Shipping",RANDBETWEEN(B2+5,B2+13),IF(C2="Standard Shipping",RANDBETWEEN(B2+3,B2+8),IF(C2="Next Day Shipping",RANDBETWEEN(B2+1,B2+2))))

B is the date column and C is the ship option column.